# R: using ellipsis argument (...)

Tags: r, ellipsis

I want to create a wrapper function replacing some of the default arguments.

Here the core of the problem I'm struggling with:

```
Error in localWindow(xlim, ylim, log, asp, ...) : 
  formal argument "cex" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

Now a bit of a context. Suppose I define a wrapper function for plot like this:

```
myplot <- function(x, ... ) {
    plot(x, cex= 1.5, ... )
}
```

If I call `myplot( 1:10, cex= 2 )` I will get the above error. I know I can turn `...` to a list

```
l <- list(...)
```

and then I could do

```
if( is.null( l[["cex"]] ) ) l[["cex"]] <- 2
```

However, how can I "insert" this list back to the ellipsis argument? Something like (I know this won't work):

```
... <- l
```

EDIT: I could use defaults in `myplot` definition (as suggested in the answer from @Thomas), but I don't want to: the function interface will become cluttered. I guess I could define a helper function like that:

```
 .myfunchelper <- function( x, cex= 2.0, ... ) {
   plot( x, cex= cex, ... )
 }

 myfunc <- function( x, ... ) {
    .myfunchelper( x, ... )
 }
```

But (i) it is less elegant and (ii) doesn't satisfy my curiosity.

Comment: Thank you, very important question, which I was now solving too! Incredible that I was just able to find it googling "R use argument in ... to override" :-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**AN ACTUAL ANSWER:**

You can do this through a bit of trickery. First, define your function as before, but include a list with your default arguments inside the function. Then you can parse whatever arguments come in through `...` as a list, replace the defaults with anything in `...` and then pass the updated list of arguments through `do.call`.

```
myplot <- function(x, ...) {
    args1 <- list(cex=4, main="Default Title") # specify defaults here
    inargs <- list(...)
    args1[names(inargs)] <- inargs
    do.call(plot, c(list(x=x), args1))
}

myplot(x=1:3) # call with default arguments
myplot(x=1:3, cex=2, main="Replacement", xlab="Test xlab") # call with optional arguments
```

**EARLIER COMMENTARY:**

The problem here can be seen through a few example functions:

```
myplot1 <- function(x, ... ) {
    plot(x, cex= 1.5, ... )
}

myplot2 <- function(x, cex=3, ... ) {
    plot(x, cex=cex, ... )
}

myplot3 <- function(x, ... ) {
    plot(x, ... )
}

myplot1(1:3, cex=3) # spits your error
myplot2(1:3, cex=3) # works fine
myplot3(1:3, cex=3) # works fine
```

In `myplot2`, you specify a default value of `cex` but can change it. In `myplot3`, `cex` is simply passed through. If you run `myplot2` with two `cex` arguments, you'll see what's happening with your function (`myplot1`):

```
myplot2(1:3, cex=3, cex=1.5) # same error as above
```

So, you're probably best to avoid setting any defaults in `plot()`, so then you can pass anything through the `...` in `myplot`.

Comment: Yeah, but this is precisely what I want to avoid. The real problem is complex, and I don't want to put the defaults in the function call definition -- there are way too many arguments already.

Comment: I've updated based on answers from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7028385/can-i-remove-an-element-in-dot-dot-dot-and-pass-it-on/7028786#7028786

Comment: Very nice answer. I have encountered the same error. I solved my problem, changing the value of some parameters in the ellipse, based on your answer: 
param = list(...);
cost = param[["cost"]];
gamma = param[["gamma"]];
# -> tune cost and gamma ->
args1 <- list(cost=bestcost, gamma=bestgamma); 
param[names(args1)] <- args1;
result = do.call(trainSVM, c(list(x = x, y = y), param));

Comment: Great answer (thanks!), but much better to use `args1 <- modifyList(args1, list(...))`. Because `args1[names(inargs)] <- inargs` would not work if `...` contains some additional arguments not present in the default args1.