# Parsing ellipsis arguments

Tags: r, ellipsis

I'm trying to write a wrapper for some ggplot2 graphs and am trying to use ellipsis' to make the function flexible.  I want to save the user (n = 1 me!) from having to explicitly pass the axis titles so thought it might be possible to parse the `...` arguments and set the axis titles appropriately.  I've read in several Stackoverflow threads ([e.g. 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057341/how-to-use-rs-ellipsis-feature-when-writing-your-own-function/3057419#3057419), [e.g. 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17390236/r-using-ellipsis-argument) or even the [R Documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Dot_002ddot_002ddot)) that ellipsis arguments can be converted to a list using `args <- list(...)` so have knocked up a simplified example...

```
test <- function(...){
    args <- list(...)
    is.list(args) %>% print()
    if(grepl('a', args)){
        title <- 'A'
    }
    else if(grepl('b', args)){
        title <- 'B'
    }
    return(title)
}
```

Testing the function I get what I expect when supplying a single `a` as an argument...

```
> test(a)
[1] TRUE
[1] "A"
```

But when I try passing other arguments including multiple one via ellipsis I don't understand what is happening. One non-`a` argument

```
> test(b)
Error in test(b) (from #2) : object 'b' not found
```

...then the first argument as `a` with secondary ones...

```
> test(a, c, d)
Error in test(a, c, d) (from #2) : object 'd' not found
```

...or non `a` at first but something further down the line which should match....

```
> test(c, b, d)
Error in test(c, b, d) (from #2) : object 'b' not found
```

The problem is cropping up at `args <- list(...)` because the logical test to see if `args` is a list isn't printed, but this doesn't fit with what I've read `list(...)` does (which is turn the ellipsis arguments into a list).  I expect I may need to use something like `args <- list(...) %>% unlist()` in order to convert the list into a vector which can then be used as an argument in `grepl()` (and have actually tried it but as far as I can tell the error is occurring before getting to the `if()`) but I don't understand whats going on and would be grateful for any explanations.

EDIT :

In light of comments it looks like this is a problem of my own creation as I'm mixing Standard and Non-Standard Evaluation.  I had been trying to write a wrapper to ggplot2 and have been using the [NSE Vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html) and [lazyeeval vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lazyeval/vignettes/lazyeval.html]) to learn/guide me (as well as various threads here on SO), but was faltering when trying to pick out specific variables from the ellipsis (`...`) to pass to the ggplot call I was making.

Downside is work want results and don't afford much time for learning/improving our coding practices so I'll switch to using Standard Evaulation and have another stab at properly understanding Non-Standard Evaluation in the future.

Comment: Seems like you have a variable named `a` defined. And there is a built in function called `c`. It's not clear what your intention is just passing in `a` vs `"a"`, the former being a symbol and the latter being a character. `ggplot` functions use a lot of non-standard evaluation which is difficult to re-create in user defined functions. Better to stick to standard evolution. In this case just wrap your parameters in quotes `test("a", "c", "d")` and use `args <- c(...)` (no need for a list)

Comment: Do you mean `if(any(grepl('a', args)))`? Assuming you use a vector as commented by @MrFlick.

Comment: Thanks both for your comments, as clocked I'm in the process of getting my head around Standard Evaluation v's Non-Standard Evaluation and guess I'm currently adrift between the two.  I currently am using non-standard evaluation but encountered problems further along with my ggplot call so opted to use `dplyr::select_(df, .dots = lazyeval::lazy_dots(...))` to subset my data, rename the variables and then call ggplot with the same name all the time (quite a fudge really).  I'm now being bitten in trying to set other components.  Annoying I don't have time to learn NSE properly.