# Call an R function with run-time generated ellipsis arguments (dot-dot-dot / three dots)

Tags: r, function, parameters, parameter-passing, ellipsis

I want to call an R function that uses the `...` (ellipsis) argument to support an undefined number of arguments:

```
f <- function(x, ...) {
  dot.args <- list(...)
  paste(names(dot.args), dot.args, sep = "=", collapse = ", ")
}
```

I can call this function passing the actual arguments predefined during design-time, e. g.:

```
> f(1, a = 1, b = 2)
[1] "a=1, b=2"
```

How can I pass actual arguments for `...` that I know only at run-time (e. g. input from the user)?

```
# let's assume the user input was "a = 1" and "b = 2"
# ------
# If the user input was converted into a vector:
> f(1, c(a = 1, b = 2))
[1] "=c(1, 2)"                # wrong result!
# If the user input was converted into a list:
> f(1, list(a = 1, b = 2))
[1] "=list(a = 1, b = 2)"     # wrong result!
```

The expected output of the dynamically generated `f` call should be:

```
[1] "a=1, b=2"
```

I have found some existing questions on how to use `...` but they did not answer my question:

[How to use R's ellipsis feature when writing your own function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3057341/4468078)

[Usage of Dot / Period in R Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9652943/4468078)

[Pass ... argument to another function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12735795/4468078)

[Can I remove an element in ... (dot-dot-dot) and pass it on?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7028385/4468078)

Comment: `dot.args <- unlist(list(...))` or `dot.args <- c(...)` seem to do what you want

Comment: @user2957945 I am not sure if I understand you right. How can I call `f()` using `dot.args <- unlist(list(...))`?

Comment: apologies, I misunderstood. I was suggesting rewriting your function using above syntax. Perhaps you want `do.call(f,  list(a = 1, b = 2))` - but prob need a check to see if input is a list or vector.

Comment: @user2957945 Strike, it works that easy! Please post this as answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by passing the function arguments using `do.call`. First force to list using `as.list`.

eg

```
input <- c(a = 1, b = 2)
do.call(f,  as.list(input))

input <- list(a = 1, b = 2)
do.call(f,  as.list(input))
```